# How can i make unit test for react component with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

i made a small react project with typescript

and i made it to print numbers of li tag to browser.

so i tried to implement unit test that test component create HTMLElement

but I really confused. I'm a newbie with typescript

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import List from "../component/List";

describe("<List />", () => {
  it("check li tags were made perfectly", async () => {
    const component = render(<List />);
    component.getByText("li");
  });
```

this code's output is error at  `render(<List />);`

my component doesn't require any props

how can i make this code is able to run properly?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting with `render(<List />);`?

Comment: Assuming you are using `CRA` my wild guess is that your test file extension is `ts`. Try to change it to `tsx` and run it again.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan - exactly, it's the cause. Thank you!
I didn't know that test file\`s extension need to be `tsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to, @Edward Choupuryan

it was just simple problem.

i wanted to test react component with typescript, and that file need to has extension `tsx` . mine was just `*.test.ts`

i changed my testfile `testfile.test.ts` to `testfile.test.tsx`, and problem solved